# Adding parameter to Restful service POST without breaking clients

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, post, parameters

I have a rest web service, which suppose has a method

```
int foo(Mytype x)
```

it has many clients, i wanted to add a parameter to to `Mytype` and change how foo behaves, As this is a restful service so all clients also implement there version of `Mytype` any ideas how to accomplish this without breaking any clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `int` to my `POST` request and it didn't break anything. So looks like adding a parameter to rest service request class is not really "Breaking Changes" but removing one will certainly break the clients.

Answer (score 0):

Have u considered versioning? E.g. server/ver2/foo

I think your only other option would be to implement the new functionality, such that it is not required, e.g.

```
foo (MyType myType) {
  if (myType.newField exists) {
  // do new stuff
  }
}
```

One final note, i would recommend combining both approaches, which will ensure that foo is backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest way would be to go with versioning.

You could provide a new version for MyType which can be handled using the MIME type description in the Accept and Content-Type headers, i.e. like so:

```
application/json+foo;application,v=2
```

Another possibility would be to handle the version via the URI/URL, i.e.

```
https://api.yourhost.com/v2/MyType
```

Like Damo already said you then have to handle the use of the different resource representations on the server.